# How can the program get multiple numbers as arguments and calculate them? Exemple: 19 10,13 4, 12 3

Tags: bash, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
# Show help function
# Call with: -h 
function help(){ cat << EOF
Arguments:
Calculate the sum of several numbers. Example: $sum 19 115 21 
                                                    10  7   3
As soon as a letter is given in the argument, the program issues an error message. 
EOF
}

#Main program
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] ; then
        help
        exit
    fi
check='^[0-9]+$'
    if ! [[ $var =~ $check ]] ; then
        echo "error: Caution! It is not a number!"
            continue
    fi

x=${1//[^0-9]/}
sum=0

for ((i=0; i<${#x}; i++));

while [[ num -gt 0 ]];do
var=$(($num % 10))
num=$(($num / 10))
sum=$(($sum + $var))
done

echo $sum
```

The program must receive one or more numbers as arguments and calculate the sum of digits for each specified number. I don't get anything.
How can the program also receive and calculate several numbers as arguments? If loops and while I have used.
The explanation must be up to 80 characters.

Comment: @Jana, have a look at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), the first point about code block formatting, and _please_ put some thought into how you indent your code; you'll see it makes it far more readable, and makes some issues (like the `for` loop missing `do` and `done`) rather more evident. Also, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a good tool for debugging shell scripts, it can automatically point out a number of issues.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you so much! I will check it in Shellcheck.

Comment: You have commas in your title data  example: `19 10,13 4, 12 3`, but none in your `$sum` example: `19 115 21` . Which is it? And if commas are important, what do they signify?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to iterate over the *digits* of a number and sum them:

```bsh
sum_digits() {
    local num=$1 len=${#1} sum=0 digit i
    for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
        digit=${num:i:1}
        sum=$((sum + digit))
    done
    echo "$sum"
}
```

then

```bsh
$ sum_digits 123
6
$ sum_digits 987654321
45
```

`${var:offset:length}` is the shell's parameter expansion to extract a *substring* out of the variable's value.

Comment: Thank you! But the digit sum must receive and calculate several numbers. For example:
./script 12 23 24 231
Answer:
12 = 3
23 = 5
24 = 6
231 = 6
But your solution just gets a number and calculates it.

Comment: you'll iterate over the numbers, and in the loop you'll call this function. Break the problem into smaller steps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it much complicated than it should be. See if this is useful to you

```
#!/bin/bash

die()
{
  echo >&2 "$@"
  exit 1
}

usage()
{
  echo >&2 "Usage: ....."
  die
}

calc() 
{ 
  if (( $# < 1 )); then usage; fi
  local args="$@"; 
  re='^[0-9]+$'
  total=0
  for n in ${args[@]}; do
   [[ $n =~ $re ]] || die "A non digit was provided"
   ((total += n))
  done
  echo "$total"
}
calc "$@"
```

You'll execute the script as

```
./script 22 20
```

And there is your answer.

Comment: Thank you! But My Example is: The sum of the digits or the checksum of a number is the sum of the individual digits of a number.
E.g .: 123 = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 or 84 = 8 + 4 = 12. Not 22 + 20 = 42

Comment: Ah nou that makes sense. So two consecutive numbers should add up?!

Comment: Yes, exactly. 22 is 4 , 20 is 2 , 11 is 2

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is not a solution to your problem, just a pointer how to tidy up the code that you already have and why it won't work, as it stands.*

---

Firstly, you need to consistently indent your code, else it will look a mess, and you can easily get lost.

Secondly, to get your code running without syntax errors you need to fix a few things:

- a missing `$` on the `num` in the `while` conditional
- missing `do` and `done` for the `for` loop.

Fixing these errors, indenting and removing some of the excessive blank lines, your code becomes:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Show help function
# Call with: -h
function help(){
cat << EOF
Arguments:
Calculate the sum of several numbers. Example: $sum 19 115 21
                                                    10  7   3
As soon as a letter is given in the argument, the program issues an error message.
EOF
}

# Main program

if [ "$1" == "-h" ] ; then
  help
  exit
fi

check='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $var =~ $check ]] ; then
   echo "error: Caution! It is not a number!"
   continue
fi

x=${1//[^0-9]/}
sum=0
for ((i=0; i<${#x}; i++)) ; do
  while [[ $num -gt 0 ]] ; do
    var=$(($num % 10))
    num=$(($num / 10))
    sum=$(($sum + $var))
  done
done
echo $sum
```

Now it *should* run, but it still won't do what you want it to.

To begin with, you don't assign `num` (nor `var`) at any point in the code. You probably mean to assign them to each of the arguments in turn:

- By not assigning `var`, you will always get the "This is not a number" error
- By not assigning `num`, your sum will always be zero

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a separation of the number validity checking and digit sum calculations from the iteration over the command-line arguments. That might make things easier to read.

The following example reports all errors encountered (and not just the first one), “because we can”.

It doesn’t support negative numbers, but Bash does, so a trivial modification to the glob (such as `@(0|-)` instead of `0`) could add that support if needed. (Then I’m not sure what the digit sum should be; maybe positive, maybe negative.)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob
set -uo pipefail

sum_digits_in_number() {
  if [[ "$1" != @(0|[1-9]*([0-9])) ]]; then
    echo -n " [['${1}' is not a number]]" 1>&2
    return 1
  fi
  local -i n="$1" sum=0
  while ((n)); do
    ((sum += n % 10)) || :
    ((n /= 10)) || :
  done
  echo -n " $((sum))"
}

sum_digits() {
  local arg
  local -i errors=0
  for arg in "$@"; do
    sum_digits_in_number "$arg" || ((++errors))
  done
  if ((errors)); then
    echo -e "\\n$((errors)) error(s)." 1>&2
    return 1
  fi
  echo
}
```

Let’s test it!

```bsh
# Valid calls:
sum_digits 19 115 21
sum_digits 0 
sum_digits 1 0
sum_digits {100..0}
sum_digits {1..100}

# Wrong calls:
sum_digits 00         # 1 error
sum_digits {0..10} z  # 1 error
sum_digits z {0..10}  # 1 error
sum_digits 1z 3 z1    # 2 errors
sum_digits a b c d    # 4 errors
```

Alternatively, you could also sum the digits by slicing the integer `$n` as if it was a string, like so:

```bsh
sum_digits_in_number() {
  if [[ "$1" != @(0|[1-9]*([0-9])) ]]; then
    echo -n " [['${1}' is not a number]]" 1>&2
    return 1
  fi
  local -i n="$1" sum=0 i
  for ((i = 0; i < ${#n}; ++i)); do
    ((sum += ${n:i:1}))
  done
  echo -n " $((sum))"
}
```

Last but not least, the `|| :` suffix is there only to make the script work (if desired) (also) in the `set -e` mode. Otherwise, if the last digit is zero, then `((sum += n % 10))` “fails”. One could instead do `sum+='n % 10'`, which would work nicely (using integer evaluation as expected) and never fail. Also, notice that the second version of `sum_digits_in_number` doesn’t have a `|| :`, simply because it iterates from the *first* digit rather than the *last* and, by prohibiting `0` as the first digit (to avoid confusion with octal numbers, e.g. `echo $((010))` says `8`), we can be sure that the `+=` will always “succeed”.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e '.put for @*ARGS.map( *.comb).map( *.sum);' 19 115 21 22 20
```

Output:

```
10
7
3
4
2
```

Above is a solution coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of languages. Briefly, command line values are accepted into the `@*ARGS` array, each value is split into individual characters (`comb`-ed), a individual characters are `sum`med.

Note, if you're interested in playing with numbers, Raku provides some very clever `Rat`-ional number functionalities , such as the `nude` ("NUmerator DEnominator") function below.

```
raku -e ' say( .nude, " == ", .Num ) for @*ARGS.map( *.Rat);' 1 2/2 1/2 3/3 2/3 1/3 4/4 3/4 2/4 1/4
```

Output:

```
(1 1) == 1
(1 1) == 1
(1 2) == 0.5
(1 1) == 1
(2 3) == 0.6666666666666666
(1 3) == 0.3333333333333333
(1 1) == 1
(3 4) == 0.75
(1 2) == 0.5
(1 4) == 0.25
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-@*ARGS
https://docs.raku.org/type/Rational
https://raku.org/